# XSLT: What is the best way to apply a floating text that will display the full expression for acronyms from an external dictionary file?

Tags: html, xslt

I'm new to XSLT.

I need to apply floating text that displays a setting for acronyms, as soon as the mouse cursor hovers over a word that is abbreviated.

My input file is XML, and every word that should display acronyms is represented in the following format:

```
    <abbreviation Id="E.G."/>
```

When the mouse cursor hovers over the word EG, the floating text will be displayed: "for example".

I thought to apply the floating text using the HTML abbr tag
And the code I wrote is:

```
    <xsl:template match="abbreviation">
        <abbr title="for example.">
            <xsl:value-of select="@Id"/>
        </abbr>
    </xsl:template>
```

I want the "title" attribute to be given as a parameter the definition of the main boxes from an external file that will contain a dictionary of related abbreviations and explanations.

I would love to know how to apply my issue.

And also get ideas about the external dictionary file - what kind of file should you create? For example, I would like a good structure of the file.

Note:
I use OXYGEN EDITOR, 
And I believe I can also get solutions in XSLT version 2 and 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, XSLT does not float any text, it is a programming language to transform XML (or with XSLT 2 or 3, other input formats) to XML, (X)HTML, plain text. You seem to want to transform your XML to HTML in the hope the HTML user agent or browser displays a tooltip of the `title` attribute.

As for using an XML file as a secondary input file, if you have `abbrvs.xml` with

```
<root><abbr key="E.G.">for example.</abbr>...</root>
```

then in XSLT you can use

```
<abbr title="{key('abbr', @Id, doc('abbrvs.xml'))}">
  <xsl:value-of select="@id"/>
</abbr>
```

to pull that `title` attribute value from the secondary input file if the XSLT declares a key

```
<xsl:key name="abbr" match="abbr" use="@key"/>
```

Comment: The floating text I receive is:
key ('abbr', @glossaryItemId, doc ('abbrvs.xml'))

Could there be a syntax error in your example?

Comment: @C.Mar, as my code suggestion does not have any text with `@glossaryItemId` it seems you have changed the code. As for a syntax omission, I had one in the initial post but corrected that 56 minutes ago while your comment 9 minutes ago should have seen the corrected example. Anyway, the other answer appeared faster and without syntax omissions so use that one and upvote it.

Comment: I changed the xslt version to 2.0 in order for the code to run. Now the html abbr tag seems correct (by OXYGEN tool), but when I loaded the html file with IE browser, the text appears with no float text, Does IE not support version 2?

Comment: If you run XSLT inside oXygen you use any of the XSLT processors oXygen supports and create a standalone result file, like an HTML file in your case. Whether that HTML file has been created with an XSLT 2 or 1 processor does not matter in any way when a web browser renders an HTML file. So your browsing experience of HTML inside IE does not depend on the XSLT version or processor you have used outside of IE. As for having a tooltip for that `title` attribute, not sure whether IE supports that and in what version or what rendering mode. You will have to ask a separate question on that, I guess.

Comment: I now have to work only with XSL version 1
According to the code you suggested, I get an error: "
Error in expression key('abbr', @Id, doc('abbrvs.xml')): Unknown system function: doc". How to fix it?

Comment: Change `<abbr title="{key('abbr', @Id, doc('abbrvs.xml'))}">` to `<abbr><xsl:variable name="id" select="@Id"/><xsl:attribute name="title"><xsl:for-each select="document('abbrvs.xml')"><xsl:value-of select="key('abbr', $id)"/></xsl:for-each></xsl:attribute>`.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose your external dictionary looks like:

**dict.xml**

```
<dictionary>
    <entry abbr="C.V.">course of life</entry>
    <entry abbr="E.G.">for example</entry>
    <entry abbr="N.B.">note well</entry>
</dictionary>
```

You can then use a **[key](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#key)** to transform an input like:

**XML**

```
<root>
    <abbreviation Id="E.G."/>
</root>
```

using:

**XSLT 2.0** (untested)

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:param name="path-to-dictionary" select="'dict.xml'"/>
<xsl:key name="abbr-lookup" match="entry" use="@abbr" />

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <html>
        <body>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="abbreviation">
    <abbr title="{key('abbr-lookup', @Id, document($path-to-dictionary))}">
        <xsl:value-of select="@Id"/>
    </abbr>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

to get:

**Result**

```
<html>
    <body>
        <abbr title="for example">E.G.</abbr>
    </body>
</html>
```

---

To understand the syntax used, read about [Attribute Value Templates](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#attribute-value-templates).

Comment: What the different between "document" function you suggested and "doc" function that Martin suggested?

Comment: @C.Mar Not much. One is an [XSLT function](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116#document), the other an [XPath 2.0 function](https://www.w3.org/TR/2010/REC-xpath-functions-20101214/#func-doc). --- P.S. I believe my answer was the first (not that it matters).